# Homebrew: change name of group ownership in /usr/local/ so admins and standard users can brew

Tags: permission, homebrew, administrator

I have a local admin user and a few "network" mobile users (without `admin` privileges) who need to be able to `brew` on a Mac. So, these 'network' users are not members of the group `admin` and probably shouldn't be.

```
$ ls -l /user/local

-rw-r--r--   1 localadmin  admin   491 Jan 21 18:04 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x   6 localadmin  admin   204 Jan 21 18:23 Cellar
drwxr-xr-x   8 localadmin  admin   272 Jan 21 18:06 Library
-rw-r--r--   1 localadmin  admin   789 Jan 21 18:04 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  44 localadmin  admin  1496 Jan 23 23:44 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 localadmin  admin   102 Jan 21 18:06 etc
drwxr-xr-x  27 localadmin  admin   918 Jan 21 18:24 include
drwxr-xr-x  98 localadmin  admin  3332 Jan 21 18:24 lib
drwxr-xr-x   6 localadmin  admin   204 Jan 21 18:24 opt
drwxr-xr-x   9 localadmin  admin   306 Jan 21 18:24 share
drwx------   3 localadmin  admin   102 Jan 21 18:37 var
```

My question is would there be a problem with, say, changing the group from `admin` to something like `brewers` for `/usr/local -R` (recurseively)? Then add `root`, `localadmin` and each network user to the `brewers` group. Would each network user now be able to `brew`?

I [have read](http://ikennaokpala.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/using-homebrew-with-multiple-users-on-a-single-machine/) that I might need to change the `umask` for each network user to `0002`?

Answer (score 1):

This can work if you also then make `/usr/local/` and everything under it group-writable with `chmod`. The current permissions have them writable only by localadmin.

Yes, you will need to do something about the `umask` for users running `brew`. Otherwise users won't be able to modify stuff brewed by other users, even if they're both in the `brewers` group. You probably don't want to change their default `umask`, because then *all* the files they create would be group-writable, which is probably not what you want. You might use a custom wrapper script around the `brew` command which sets the `umask` to 002 for just the duration of that command, e.g. by doing the `umask` and `brew` calls in a subshell.